# Have both JSX and normal className together

Tags: javascript, html, css, xml, reactjs

I have a css style class that needs to be in JSX form as it depends on the state, but I also need to use style class the ordinary way for styling. How do I combine these together?
I've tried

```
<span className={statusColor} className="uppercase">
```

Which only takes into account the last class one

```
<span className={statusColor uppercase}>
```

Which obviously looks for a variable called uppercase and errors out

```
<span className="uppercase {statusColor}">
```

Neither of them work

Below is a dummied-down version of my code. What is the correct way to do this?

```
const Component = React.createClass({
    return {
      completed: false
    }
  },
  render () {
    let statusColor;
    this.state.completed === true ? statusColor = "green" : statusColor = "red";
    return (
      <div className="status-banner">
        <span className="kata-text-status">Status: <span className={statusColor} className="uppercase">{this.state.completed.toString()}</span></span>
      </div>
    )
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<span className={`uppercase ${statusColor}`}>
```

This will use an ES6 template string (`` `uppercase ${statusColor}` ``) and interpolate `statusColor` with `${...}`.

Answer (score 2):

```
<span className={'uppercase' + ' ' + statusColor}>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in several ways.

Firstly you can use + to concat more than one string variables and generate dynamic strings

```
<span className={"uppercase " + statusColor}>
```

Or you can use npm modules [classnames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames).

Comment: Thanks, just have to add a space after uppercase or it looks for a class called "uppercasestatusColor"

Answer (score 0):

The brackets `{}` translate to normal JS. So you can just use `+` to concatenate.

```
<span className={"uppercase " + statusColor}>
```

Comment: "+ has unexpected token", I had to wrap everything in { }.Thanks though